# Font awesome icons in html form

Tags: html, css, forms

I'd like to include font awesome icons in a html form(Like username and password text box).If I give it as a placeholder,it disappears as soon as I click the text box.I'd like to have it this way:The placeholder(Eg:"Username" as a text) should vanish as soon as I click the text box while the font awesome icon(Eg:User icon) shouldn't vanish when I click the text box.What should I do ?

Comment: Could you give us the actual example of what you've tried so far ? (either straight code or jsfiddle link)

Comment: This is the code I tried:                                                           <body>
<div class="login">
<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="usname" placeholder="&#xf007">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p class="wrapper"><input placeholder="&#61447; Username"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative; 
}

input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; } /* This is for the placeholder */

.wrapper:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -5px;
    content: "\f007";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/0osgcoue/

---

**EDIT:** Here is an alternative (not within the input but it will so it will not go away.)

```
<label id="email-label2">
    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
    <input type="text"id="email2" placeholder="email here" />
</label>
```

**CSS**:

```
#email-label2 {
    position: relative;
}

#email-label2 .fa-rocket {
    color: #666;
    top: 2px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#email2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/xs459ab2/

You need to compromise on something!

Comment: This one works, but I'd like to have the icon in my textbox even when the user types(or after typed) the input..

Answer (score 0):

Just add the icons inside the labels for the fields?

```
<form>
    <label for="user">Username <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></label><input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username"/>
    <label for="pass">Password <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i></label><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mdzjer1o/